# WPF Application doesnt start

Tags: .net, wpf, frameworks

I have a problem with a computer (Windows XP, X86, Framewok 3.5 Sp1), but the user is not administrator.

I did some tests :
- WPF Application with framework 3.5 (empty window) : the application run correctly.
- WPF Application with framework 3.5 (window with simple button in grid) : application doesn't run : the process exist but it consume 50% of CPU and nothing happens !

I launched "netfx_setupverifier" program  : no problem detected.
What can i do ?

Comment: What happens if you run it from the command line? Anything different?

Answer (score 1):

Attach visual studio debugger and check what is going on inside. Where are the threads and what are their stack traces.